# Using JavaScript to open a window to a specific size

Tags: javascript, html, href

I'm wanting to open a window to a specific size using the window.open method when my button div is clicked. I referenced some other online sources, and got it this far.

```
<div class="button" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'width=600', 'height=600');return false;"></div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the width works in firefox, however the height does not. None of it works in Chrome.

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) and look at the examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the window options go in one string:

```
<div class="button" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'width=600, height=600');return false;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This below code should help you with your issue,

```
<div class="button" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'width=600, height=600');return false;"></div>
```

Try it out and let me know.